# Garbled character output when using cout API

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, winapi

I am trying to run this simple code in VS 2015

```
#include "stdafx.h"
# include <iostream>

int main()
{
    char * szOldPath = "\"C:\icm\scripts\StartupSync\runall.bat\" nonprod"; 
    std::cout << szOldPath << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

However, the output of szOldPath is not proper and the console is printing--

```
unall.bat" nonprodupSync
```

I suspect this might be because of Unicode and I should be using wcout. So I disabled Unicode by going to Configuration Properties -> General --> Character Set and tried setting it to Not Set or Multi Byte. But still running into this issue.

I understand it is not good to disable UNICODE but I am trying to understand some legacy code written in our company and this experiment is a part of this exercise,is there any way I can get the cout command to print szOldPath  successfully?

Comment: You need to escape some of the sequences starting with `\\` characters as they form valid escape sequences: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape

Comment: Richard, thanks for your prompt answer. I also had a follow up question, if we use count instead of wcout, we should always disable UNICODE right ?

Comment: You can intermix `cout` and `wcout` without problem as long as you pass the right type of strings to them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue has nothing to do with Unicode.

`\r` is the [escape sequence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape) for a carriage return.  So, you are printing out `"C:\icm\scripts\StartupSync`, and then `\r` tells the terminal to move the cursor back to the beginning of the current line, and then `unall.bat" nonprod` is printed, overwriting what was already there.

You need to escape all of the `\` characters in your string literal, just like you had to escape the `"` characters.

Also, your variable needs to be declared as a pointer to `const char` when assigning a string literal to the pointer.  This is enforced in C++11 and later:

```cpp
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    const char * szOldPath = "\"C:\\icm\\scripts\\StartupSync\\runall.bat\" nonprod"; 
    std::cout << szOldPath << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Alternatively, in C++11 and later, you can use a *raw string literal* instead to avoid having to escape any characters with a leading `\`:

```cpp
const char * szOldPath = R"("C:\icm\scripts\StartupSync\runall.bat" nonprod)";
```